# Timestamp problem showing 1970 instead of 1988

Tags: blackberry, timestamp

I am trying to set default value in DateField using the following statement

DateField dateField = new DateField("Birthday:", 567993600, DateField.DATE | DateField.FIELD_LEFT);

but when I run my application it shows me 7 Jan 1970 instead of 1 Jan 1988.

I checked the time stamp on http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

and it shows me correct expected date which is,  "Fri, 01 Jan 1988 00:00:00 GMT"

I am using 8900 simulator and my date time is correct showing today's date 31 Dec 2010 in date time under options folder.

Regards,

-gmuhammad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The date field uses milliseconds](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/DateField.html#getDate%28%29). You need to multiply the time with 1000.

**Edit**: Make sure you are using long values (i.e. 5679936001000l or 567993600l*1000). Using ints, the multiplication overflows.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

**DateField dateField = new DateField("Birthday:", 567993600000L, DateField.DATE | DateField.FIELD_LEFT);**

Martin, you answer was quite right but after multiplying with 1000 there was an overflow, compiler was using integer for the literals. So I append three zeros in the end instead of multiplying with 1000.

**Thanks Martin.**

Comment: To All,

Most of the sites on internet uses UTC without millisecs, So be careful if you are developing for blackberry.

Comment: @Arhimed: you didn't get the point, I also agree with Maritin's answer but as you can see after mulitiplying with 1000 you can have overflow if you do not explicitly append L (to be treated as long by compiler), Which is also specified by Martin(after he edit his answer). So instead of Multiplying with 1000 it's better to append 3 zeros with L, to satisfy the compiler.